# projecting / starting medical information app on Android

Tags: android, medical

I would like to create a **custom open source information management application**, that I could adapt to practical needs of a **psychiatrist**. (and also would really like to avoid inventing the wheel). Could someone advise me what would be a good way to start? I have some amateur programming experience (see below), but I have little experience with java and eclipse (which I have set up with Android SDK plugin on my linux PC).

What I would like to achieve is a simple app where I could relatively easily re-program/rearrange information presenting screens. I would like the major development stages to be something like:

1. Basic framework of the app is done Main information is added
   through the programming environment

   - basic formatting (bold, color, lists) should be supported
   - I imagine this would be through HTML/CSS markup Hierarchical (not
     too deep) screens with concise information about conditions,
     treatments; easy, not too cumbersome navigation is a must.
   - Possibility to attach own notes from android device
     on every piece of information (e.g. on medical condition, on medication,
     list of differential diagnoses, etc)
2. A desktop application that allows for easy adding and editing
   of the content

   - initially could be even sqlite manager or something similar
3. possibility for adding images,

   - possibility to add rating scales, which would calculate scores
   - maybe also possibility to print through some android print driver

*** in essence I envision this as a sort of an integrated website with a relatively simple database behind it (sqlite?) running on android. My models would be epocrates and medscape apps, but the content would be more specific to everyday psychiatric practice. It would include aspects of psychological therapies as well.

In about a years time, I think, the content would be interesting enough to see whether the app should go on the market.

**My (limited) experience:**

I am a MD - a Psychiatrist. I have some amateur development experience (php, html, css, Perl, bash, sed, sql, Access and some time ago - AS/400). I would like to start an app that I could modify as I go - in order to have the most useful info at my fingertips, when I need it in my work. I have considered some databases (e.g. HandDB) but my experience with them is that you get very constricted with their user interface and this hinders fast information retrieval when you need it. Adding information can be clumsy as well.

**Why I am asking for help here**

Most of tasks above seem pretty standard. I imagine that people with lots of programming experience here, probably would be able to point me towards some information that would help me to get started.

Many thanks for considering this :)

Comment: @user635540: This is a question-and-answer site, for programming questions. You have not asked any programming questions, other than something so vague ("Could someone advise me what would be a good way to start?") that it doesn't really make sense on this site. Visit http://developer.android.com, download the tools, and start in on lightweight test apps. Gain relevant experience, and in time you can start in on your project. When you have *concrete* questions, we may be able to give you a hand here.

Comment: Well - thanks for the reply. I know the question is rather broad, but that is why I have tried to outline what I am trying to achieve. With the answers you have provided, I am sure I will get more specific coding questions pretty soon.

Comment: how are you getting on with your project? Just thought I'd mention that phonegap can be rather useful for non-professional programmers getting started developing phone apps

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to develop this app? Everything you mentioned can be easily done by reading the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html). Although if its you doing the coding i recommend [buying a book](http://commonsware.com/Android/)

You will find a lot of [samples](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/index.html) and [other support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html) in the android doc

Printing can be also setup using [Google Cloud print](http://www.dkszone.net/print-documents-emails-iphone-android-google-cloud-print)

If you want to open source your application you can always use [google code](http://code.google.com/opensource/).
You have asked a really broad question here. But i guess the above information is good to get you started.

Comment: Hi guys, many thanks for this - it is a very useful start. I have now got the Commonsware books and it looks they are going to provide me exactly with what I need.